# How to add default in every case in c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, default

how do i add default in every case?
it does not allow me to do it like this and will error in the second default,

```
switch (select)
{
    
    case 1:
        here1:
        cout<<"statement"<<endl;
        
    default:
        cout<<"statement"<<endl;
        goto here1;         

        break;
        

    case 2:
        here2:
        cout<<"statement"<<endl;
        
    default:
        cout<<"statement"<<endl;
        goto here2;         

        break;
```

[i need default inside every case, how am i gonna do that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op5iP.png)

Comment: Do you know what `default` does? If you have two (or more) `default`-cases, which one should be executed? This sounds like a [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info), what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Even if this compiled your `goto`s would produce an infinite loop?

Comment: There should be one or zero  `default:` cases. Not more than that. It does not make sense to have more than that. The default is a catch all for any value that is not in the cases you have of your switch.

Comment: Step 1: forget that you ever heard of `goto`, and learn about structured loops like everyone else has for the past fifty-something years.

Comment: Realize that a case/default statement look like a LABEL (yes, as in C++ goto/label).  What would a program do if you had a `goto xyzzy`, but there were 2 `xyzzy` labels?

Comment: Think of `default` as the last `else` in this: `if(select==1) {...} else if(select==2) {...} else { /* default */ }` (if you have normal `break`s in your `case`s that is).

Comment: The problem with your logic is that execution should not get to `case 2` because `case 2` would be the `default` of `case 1`.

Comment: hello, i am a new student and trying to learn nested if statement transform into switch, my default was suppose to be the else, the default is supposed to return to the "here1" in case if the statement is not met. for example if the user chose case 2, it will input something and if it fails it will go to default and do the input again, same as the other

Comment: @Veas That's not very logical. First, you should understand what `default` does and how a `switch` in general differs from `if/else`. Then you should think about the logic in general. When the condition is not met (when `default` is hit) you got to `case 1` and execute the logic, as if `case 1` was hit in the first place. So the actual case doesn't even matter, you always execute `case 1`.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to execute the same piece of code for every case so why can't you just do so.

default just works if "incase nothing works" and if something works default doesn't execute.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

well you really cant do this because "default" considered as a case itself so you cant make two cases in one.  but instead if you want so mimic it you can use an "if statement " with the condition you want.